# MongoDB Lookup optimization

Tags: mongodb

Lookup between 2 collections that each have about 30k records and 7 compared properties is slower than expected, this is the query :

```
db.getCollection("collection1").explain("executionStats").aggregate([
    {
      "$lookup":{
         "from":"collection2",
         "let":{
            "key1":"$_key.STUDYID",
            "key2":"$_key.USUBJID",
            "key3":"$_key.QSSPID",
            "key4":"$_key.QSTEST",
            "key5":"$_key.QSCAT",
            "key6":"$_key.QSSCAT",
            "key7":"$_key.VISIT"
         },
         "pipeline":[
            {
               "$match":{
                  "$expr":{
                     "$and":[
                        {
                           "$eq":[
                              "$_key.STUDYID",
                              "$$key1"
                           ]
                        },
                        {
                           "$eq":[
                              "$_key.USUBJID",
                              "$$key2"
                           ]
                        },
                        {
                           "$eq":[
                              "$_key.QSSPID",
                              "$$key3"
                           ]
                        },
                        {
                           "$eq":[
                              "$_key.QSTEST",
                              "$$key4"
                           ]
                        },
                        {
                           "$eq":[
                              "$_key.QSCAT",
                              "$$key5"
                           ]
                        },
                        {
                           "$eq":[
                              "$_key.QSSCAT",
                              "$$key6"
                           ]
                        },
                        {
                           "$eq":[
                              "$_key.VISIT",
                              "$$key7"
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         "as":"MatchedRecords"
      }
   },
```

This takes somewhere between 3.7 ~ 4.1 seconds, I have created a compound index for all these keys : [image]
Is there any way to optimize this further?

Comment: Have you indexed **both** collections?

Comment: Yes i indexed both collection alltough it seems that indexing the origin collection does not change anything performance wise.